# WordPress 5 and BootStrap Buttons

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently, I'm working on pages for a BootStrap to WordPress theme. I have the code to a button like this:

```
<center>
<a href="http://www.retrobaseball.info"><button type="button" class="btn btn- 
danger btn-lg">Visit Site</button></a>
</center>
```

However, it shows an html button instead of the BootStrap styled button. Previously with WordPress 4 and BootStrap, I rarely had any troubles with BootStrap elements displaying. Is this something new with WordPress 5?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it to work. I suppose it took a minute for WordPress to 'digest' it. I also installed the BootStrap shortcodes for WordPress plugin before I asked the question here. Perhaps it took a minute for it to adjust to my site. Hmm...